cannot set hardware accelerator to 'none' in runtime settings
From Runtime -> change runtime type, I cannot find a menu that allows me to change the hardware accelerator type to 'none'
enter image description here
I tried different browsers (microsoft edge), restarted the program, but still cannot find the option 'none'

Same here. Did you find any solution?

I found out that choosing the 'cpu' option runs the colab with your local hardware. Hope this helps!
